# Need to caall different function on the each tabs click in the material design tabs.?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to call the different functions on each tabs click event in Angular material design tabs.

I had already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50574107) solution but it is not working.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include what isn't working when you implement the linked solution? Maybe provide an [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below -

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="onTabSwitch($event.tab.textLabel)">
 <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</mat-tab>
 <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Here is component ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'tabs-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'tabs-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['tabs-overview-example.css'],
 })

 export class TabsOverviewExample {

 public onTabSwitch(tabName: string) {
   if (tabName == 'Tab 1') {
     this.funA();
   } else {
     this.funB();
   }
 }

 public funA() {
   console.log('Called funA');
  }

 public funB() {
   console.log('Called funB');
  }
}
```

I've updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ccyirv-5n9zve)